# Launching multiple spring boot instances but one hostname for local development

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I want to launch 10 spring boot instances, I guess on multiple ports or running on the same JVM.  How do I accomplish a system such that one client will connect to the same host but could possibly hit multiple spring boot services.  Normally I launch one REST controller/service under one JVM and one spring boot instance  with one host and port.  How do I accomplish multiple instances with multiple controllers

Comment: You could hook up a discovery service + api gateway easily enough, I guess it depends on why you _need_ 10 instances locally.

Comment: Well it would be 10+ different endpoints locally.  I guess I could run 10 endpoints under the same JVM, but I was curious if you launch multiple spring boot instances even for local development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Darren and @MohamedSanaulla suggested you can use service discovery (Eureka) and Api gateway (Zuul) to achieve what you want, basically Eureka is a service discovery which keeps track of all the services registered to it on the other hand Zuul act api gateway to forward all your request to the designated service, also Zuul internally uses Ribbon, so you don't have to worry about client side load-balancing and at end you can deploy all services in docker containers and manage them using docker swarm to scale up/down without any hassle.
A working example of Eureka, Zuul using docker and docker-compose can be found [here](https://github.com/akhil6095/Spring-cloud-app).

Comment: Looks good, this is even for a local development configuration?

Comment: Yes you can setup up default profiles to just connect into a local running Eureka Service - deployed regions obviously need different configuration but that should be handled via profiles or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can do client side load balancing using Netflix Ribbon. There is a spring guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/)